# Simple app with android

Tags: android

I use the following php.

```
<?php
$status = "0";
$message = "Success";

$result = ['status' => $status, 'message' => $message];
die(json_encode($result));
?>
```

I have checked with REST client. It returns data.

I have created the simple log in in Android which contains `two text fields and one button`. I have configured in the xml for the button click.

I am using android volley.

```
public void checkLogin(View view){
    final String emailText = email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String passwordTex = password.getText().toString().trim();

    if(emailText.isEmpty() || passwordTex.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter all the details",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://10.0.2.2:8080/localhost/test_login.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", emailText);
                params.put("password", passwordTex);
                return params;
            }
        };
        req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                5000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(req);
    }
        String g = emailText.toString();
}
```

I debugged the code and got `timeout` error. I have added `retry policy` also.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: From the IP Address i guess you are trying to run the App in an emulator? Do you have network access at all in the emulator?

Comment: @J.Dow I don't understand your question because I am completely new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly be sure that you have network access permission on your app manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If you use emulator use your computer **IP** address instead of **localhost**. I suggest to you [read this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Comment: if you have no permission app wil be crashed

Comment: no. I am using apache server. so localhost means my server.

Comment: Problem is there your server ip is 10.0.2.2 not localhost. Just replace 10.0.2.2:80/test_login.php if you php file is under a file add file name to path

Comment: No. Your server ip address is 10.0.2.2:8080. So when you want to connect login php your url will be your_server_ip_address/path_to_php_file